# How to remove modulation frequency and its harmonics

Tags: matlab, filters, frequency-spectrum

I have amplitude modulated sound file signal and after demodulation using FFT I got fundamental frequency and its harmonics and of course noise.

How to remove that fundamental modulation frequency and its harmonics from spectrum using Matlab… any suggestion… m-file…?

Comment: Please clarify your question. What kind of AM signal is it (DSB-LC, etc)? How did you demodulate it? Why do you have noise? What do you mean by 'fundamental modulation frequency'? Why do you want to remove it?

Comment: I found the solution, I will use notch multiply filter.